# FATAL: role "root" does not exist ? Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I run docker container with following command

```
docker run --name postgres14 -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=root -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass -d postgres:14-alpine
```

And I want to connect to my Postgres database and get error

```
FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

My connection to db:

[image]

How to connect to my db?

Comment: Specify a `POSTGRES_USER` that actually _does_ exist instead? How are _we_ supposed to know which usernames are valid for _your_ database?

Comment: is it not created db with user root inside the container ?

Comment: If it gives you that error, obviously not. We'd need to look at the Dockerfile for that specific container to say more, but _typically_ the default superuser account is for the user (like `postgres`) that the database server itself runs as. Some folks packaging postgres set up a default `pg_hba.conf` (the config file controlling authorization) that lets every local user connect as itself with the operating system's authentication as permissions, but that's not a particularly good practice, and doesn't make much sense in a container anyhow.

Comment: Anyhow -- we're here for questions about writing software; not questions about using software someone else wrote and packaged. If you want to know how to authenticate to a database server instance you're using unmodified from a container someone else wrote, that container's documentation is the best place to start.

Answer (score 5):

Ok , this  issue occurs only in Mac m1. Solution is run port 5433:5432

Comment: So, it sounds like you already had something running on 5432, so couldn't start another thing there.  Your docker run command should have thrown an error over that (that is what mine does anyway, but I'm not using a Mac.)