# PGVector from LangChain as a vector database for a retrieval augmented generation (RAG) application

Tags: postgresql, vector, word-embedding, langchain, pgvector

https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/pgvector

One of the required args in `PGVector.from_documents()` is `connection_string`, which is the connection str to the PostgreSQL database. The format of `connection_string` is `postgresql://username:password@host:port/databasename` so I used `postgresql://tombomer:Passw0rd1@localhost:5432/postgres` which (I think) corresponds to a DB I set up earlier using the `psql` CLI

I ran the following commands:

- `psql postgres` which I think enables the psql CLI for the default Postgres DB then connected to my DB called `postgres` and did `CREATE EXTENSION pgvector;` and `CREATE EXTENSION vector;`
- the `vector` command worked fine but `pgvector` gave `ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/Users/tombomer/homebrew/share/postgresql@14/extension/pgvector.control": No such file or directory`

I then run the Python script and get a lengthy output, the error being: `sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) malformed array literal: "[-0.40820312,0.19042969...]"`

I've also been following this: https://bugbytes.io/posts/vector-databases-pgvector-and-langchain/ but when I get to `CREATE EXTENSION pgvector;` I get the same `could not open extension control file` error as above

TLDR: **how should I configure my Postgres DB and what should the connection string be?**

Answer (score 0):

[FATAL: role "root" does not exist ? Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73681385/fatal-role-root-does-not-exist-docker/73681896#73681896) - this solved it for me I think because I am using an M1 Mac. Run port **5433**:5432 instead of 5432:5432